# How to Know the no of Images got selected using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, android-intent

How to check whether user selected multiple images or single Image from list of images opened from Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT). Which Activity will be invoked for this Action?

AFAIK  from app OnActivityResult Intent's getdata() has to be used for single Image selection and getClipdata() for multiple image selection.Is this efficient way or any other direct way to get this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just searched android source for answer Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT opens DocumentsActivity with in that the following code is used to construct intent data in onTaskFinished()

```
  void onTaskFinished(Uri... uris) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onFinished() " + Arrays.toString(uris));

    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (uris.length == 1) {
        intent.setData(uris[0]);
    } else if (uris.length > 1) {
        final ClipData clipData = new ClipData(
                null, mState.acceptMimes, new ClipData.Item(uris[0]));
        for (int i = 1; i < uris.length; i++) {
            clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item(uris[i]));
        }
        intent.setClipData(clipData);
    }
```

I think if length is one code using setData otherwise setClipData means the to do null check for getData or getClipData is the only way to get info about the no of Images selected. Finally if getData is not null only one image selected otherwise getClipData().getItemCount gives the count of images selected